# CGRect logic in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, coordinates, intersection, cgrect

I am porting a 2d game from UIKit to Cocos2d. One part of it, which sets the frame for five different squares, looked like this when I used UIKit:

```
- (void)setFrames {
    [playerSquare setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];

    for(int iii = 0; iii < [squares count]; iii++) {
        int randX = arc4random() % 321;
        int randY = arc4random() % 481;

        [(UIButton*)[squares objectAtIndex:iii] setFrame:CGRectMake(randX, randY, [(UIButton*)[squares objectAtIndex:iii] frame].size.width, [(UIButton*)[squares objectAtIndex:iii] frame].size.height)];

        CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(80, 160, 160, 160);

        for(UIButton* b in squares) {
            if((CGRectIntersectsRect(b.frame, [(UIButton*)[squares objectAtIndex:iii] frame]) && ![b isEqual:[squares objectAtIndex:iii]])) {
                //make sure no two squares touch
                iii--;
                break;
            } else if(CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect, [(UIButton*)[squares objectAtIndex:iii] frame])) {
                //no square is close to center of the screen
                iii--;
                break;
            } else if(!CGRectContainsRect(CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 460), [(UIButton*)[squares objectAtIndex:iii] frame])) {
                //no square is close to the edges of the screen
                iii--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I have tried to accomplish the same thing in cocos2d:

```
- (void)setFrames {
    for(int idx = 0; idx < [squares count]; idx--) {
        int randX = arc4random() % 321;
        int randY = arc4random() % 481;

        [(CCSprite*)[squares objectAtIndex:idx] setPosition:ccp(randX, randY)];

        CGRect playerRect = CGRectMake(80, 160, 160, 160);

        for(CCSprite* b in squares) {
            if( (CGRectIntersectsRect(b.boundingBox, [(CCSprite*)[squares objectAtIndex:idx] boundingBox]) && ![b isEqual:[squares objectAtIndex:idx]]) ) {
                //make sure no two squares touch
                idx--;
                break;
            } else if(CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect, [(CCSprite*)[squares objectAtIndex:idx] boundingBox])) {
                //no square is close to center of the screen
                idx--;
                break;
            } else if(!CGRectContainsRect(CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 460), [(CCSprite*)[squares objectAtIndex:idx] boundingBox])) {
                //no square is close to the edges of the screen
                idx--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this modified method doesn't work. One of the squares gets put in the proper position, but the other four always spawn at cocos2d point 0, 0. (bottom left corner of the screen) Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What are the randX randY coordinates? I suppose they're hardly going to be 0,0 for 3 of the 4 sprites, so I can only imagine that you change the position again somewhere else.

Comment: Look at the for loop declaration one more time :) It will all become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out the problem- can't believe I did this. At one point in this method, I had the for loop set up as:

```
for(int idx = [squares count] - 1; idx >= 0; idx--)
```

instead of

```
for(int idx = 0; idx < [squares count]; idx++)
```

As you can see in the code I have above, I forgot to change the decrement part of the loop to increment from decrement. So, the reason only the first sprite was being set was that the loop started at 0, then `idx` was decremented until it overran the lower bound of an int and went to an `int`s upper bound, which was more than `[squares count]`. So, the only problem with my new code was the difference between idx++ and idx--.

Frustrating mistake.